# External SSD no longer being detected - Mac - Lightroom (?)

Tags: mac, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk, adobe-lightroom

I am running macOS Monterey 12.6 (context)

I have a 500gb Sandisk SSD from 2019. I filled it to 75% with photos from my phone and my cameras over the years. I used lightroom to edit said photos.

Recently, I was moving and renaming some folders and such on the drive directly. I also added new photos.

Then, all of a sudden, the stuff in the drive was slow to load. I thought this was a storage issue so I cleared photos to return back to ~75%. Also, lightroom was no longer able to find the photos. Ops, Lightroom wants you to move and rename folders in their software. Ok, I reimported everything into lightroom and I will rename and move some stuff there.

**However, an issue  with the drive developed. Long load times for folders to load occurred, sometimes there would be no loading and the graphical paths were blank; further, I was stopped for ejecting the drive because "an application is using the drive" and quitting all software would not solve the issue. Other times, the drive would just stop being accessible mid use. Even more, the drive was also not being detected, it would take a couple reboots, disconnects, and reconnects to get the disk detected.**

I put off storing the data elsewhere because I thought I knew how to get the drive recognized: reboot the computer with the drive plugged in and I am good. It worked once but today, it ceased to be recognized. I have tried each of my 4 USB-C drives to no avail.

System report says there is a sandisk SSD plugged in, [image: System Report]

and `diskutil` also finds it (sometimes but not always) [image: diskutil]

What is going on? What can I do? :(((((((
Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an outside chance the enclosure is failing, but equally likely the drive itself.
You could try shucking the drive & moving to a new enclosure; but beyond that, I'd be looking at your backup or a data recovery company.

Comment: what would it mean that the enclosure is failing? I am open to reading more if you prefer not to explain.

Comment: Something is failing. As you can't run SMART tests over USB, the logical course would be to test the two probabilities empirically.

Comment: ahhh, yes. Thank you. I ended up sending to data recovery. If it was not the enclosure, what could be the likely culprit? I heard something about possible core degradation, esp since I did not know that SSD are not good for long term, cold, storage. I also ended up yanking the drive when safe ejection was refused by my computer because "a program is using it" despite all known programs being closed.

Comment: Its cool if you do not care to respond, just interested and wanted to have my experience documented for anyone else who might run into this problem. thank you @Tetsujin

Comment: It does sound like it was already failing, but yanking a drive without eject, especially whilst still in use could have itself been the final straw. This can be terminal for any FAT-type format, journaling on HFS/APFS would make rescue attempts slightly easier perhaps. I wish you luck.